# JQuery - Dynamically Adding a New DIV Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have been researching a clean way to add a DIV to a page and add a line of text dynamically. However most of the stuff I come across deals with existing DIVs in the page already and not exactly creating a new one.

I am not super familiar with JQuery but I am getting there and tried this code but for some reason not getting the desired result, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var theResponse = prompt('Which Group?');
//alert(theResponse);
var groupDiv = $('#groupDiv');
$('body').append(groupDiv);
$('#groupDiv').css({"marginLeft":"10px", "marginTop":"10px"});
$('#groupDiv').append("Group: "+theResponse);
$('#groupDiv').show();
switch (theResponse) 
{
    case "1":
    //alert("case 1");
        break;
    case "2":
    //alert("case 2");
        break;
    case "3":
    //alert("case 3");
        break;
    default:
    //alert("default");
        //
}
```

I am hoping its not some dumb rookie mistake but any help is appreciated. I am running it using GreaseMonkey and TamperMonkey with all of the code working fine (meaning everything besides that first DIV creation).

Comment: building on a previous response, if this is what you're trying to achieve.. http://jsfiddle.net/27Dup/1/. You don't really need to use the `switch` statement here unless of course you want the result to differ depending on the value entered in the prompt, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Yes this is what I need, thank you. The switch is necessary for the rest of the code, I just took them out to avoid making the code too long and hard to read since only the part at the top was my area of issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

```
var theResponse = prompt('Which Group?');
$('body').append('<div id="groupDiv"></div>');
$("#groupDiv").css({"marginLeft":"10px", "marginTop":"10px"});
$('#groupDiv').text("Group: " + theResponse);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeFZ2/)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed and I see my mistake. Lesson learned and thank you again.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Could you maybe accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
var groupDiv = $('#groupDiv');
```

You get an existing element with id groupDiv. If you append it somewhere, you remove it from the previous place. If you want to clone it (duplicate), use:

```
var groupDiv = $('#groupDiv').clone();
```

If you want to create something from scratch, use:

```
var groupDiv = $('<div class="groupDiv"></div>');
```

You can also add all parameters in one go:

```
var groupDiv = 
    $('<div class="groupDiv" style="marginLeft:10px, marginTop:10px">Group: ' +
    theResponse + '</div>');
```

And then add to the body as you did:

```
$('body').append(groupDiv);
```

You don't need to `show()` if it wasn't hidden, or if it didn't had `display:none` style.

Comment: Thank you, I learned now what I did was wrong, thanks for the extended explanation. Cool, I can add everything in one shot, sweet. Gotcha, the `.show()` was a desperate attempt thinking maybe I needed to say show me the new div for it to do it, now I know better :)